# Can't import java.net.*

Tags: java, netbeans, libraries

I'm trying to do `import java.net.*;` on a Java Web Project in Netbeans but it keeps saying that the java.net package does not exist while if I do this on a "normal" Java application it doesn't give me any error.

I tried to download JAXP.jar and add it do the Libraries hoping that it would fix the java.net missing but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how can I import java.net library on a Java Web Project?

Comment: You mean jsf project? If so you can in managed beans.

Comment: The jar is not present on the classpath in Netbeans. Try adding that to project settings

Comment: @Muhammad Hewedy This project: http://s23.postimg.org/pis59dnq3/dfgsdgdg.png

Comment: @gonephishing Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Delete this project and create a new one under the 'java web' menu on the left, or better go and use maven.

Comment: @Muhammad Hewedy The problem with java web is that it only has Web Application and not Web Project so I can't deploy it.

Comment: Use maven much better

Comment: @Muhammad Hewedy Will follow you advice. Thanks

Comment: If it's just a simple java web project, I'll recommend not to look much into maven. You may end up learning it but it won't be of much use unless you work on bigger projects. Also adding a jar to class path is much much easier and will hardly take seconds. You have to make a few edits in the project build path setting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import the same package in netbeans in my java web project(not maven). [image: check]

Try following in order:

- take backup of all your projects
- Reinstall JDK
- reinstall Netbeans
- Recreate java web project in netbeans and give us
  feedback